# Redirect between pages - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-portlet-mvc

I am beginning with `Spring Portlet MVC` but I believe this question also applies to `Spring MVC`. Let me show you this example

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="VIEW")//this maps to Portlet Mode VIEW
public class LoginController {

    @RenderMapping("action=showRegisterPage")
    //this annotation is almost the same like @RequestMapping
    public String showRegisterPage() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("loginForm")
    public LoginForm getLoginForm() {
        return new LoginForm();
    }
}
```

and then controller for registration page

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="VIEW")
public class RegistrationController {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUser() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

And the problem is, when I call the showRegisterPage method (action) from page I get redirected to registration.jsp but this exceptions occurs

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor 
plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

This can be fixed by putting `ModelAttribute` user to LoginController but code duplication is not really right way, so how can I solve this correctly?I have also tried moving showRegisterPage method to RegistrationController but then the link is not working. Maybe somebody could elaborate how exactly binding of page to some controller works?

P.S. Both index.jsp and registration.jsp contains `<form:form>` tag and I also omitted boilerplate code from both controllers.

Comment: The 'user' attribute needs to be added to the Model which then will be automatically bound to request scope. Without that, there will be error. Please see Georgy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown because when you go to the registration page model doesn't have user attribute. I guess that your register page contains smth like this

```
<form:form commandName="user" >
```

That's why when you paste this code to first controller error is gone

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public User getUser() {
    return new User();
}
```

this code provide user object to model.
If you not want copy one method two times you can

```
@RenderMapping("action=showRegisterPage")
//this annotation is almost the same like @RequestMapping
public String showRegisterPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "registration";
}
```

In this case model will be contain user object.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the showregistrationpage method should b part of the registration controller rather than the login controller.